Bison balanced parentheses grammar
With current parser im able to do both of these:
let (x, y, z) = (10, true, 5);
let (x) = (10);
but I cant do this:
let (((x)), y, z) = (10, true, 5);
This is my grammar.y:
identifierlist: identifier COMMA identifierlist                     { $$ = new PairIdentifierList($1, $3); }
              | identifier                                          { $$ = new LastIdentifierList($1); }
              | LPAREN identifier RPAREN                            { $$ = new LastIdentifierList($2); }
              | LPAREN identifierlist RPAREN                            { $$ = $2; }
              ;

identifier: IDENTIFIER         { $$ = new Identifier($1); };


What is the issue?
There are multiple issues such as ambiguity and conflicts. The most likely culprit is a shift/reduce conflict in your piece of grammar. This means that upon evaluating your input there are scenarios where both reducing a production rule or shifting a terminal on the stack are both valid. The shift-reduce parser does not know which action to take and defaults to shifting.
Where does this shift/reduce conflict come from?
Look at the grammar:
identifierlist: identifier COMMA identifierlist
              | identifier
              | LPAREN identifier RPAREN
              | LPAREN identifierlist RPAREN
;

The minimal example illustrating the shift/reduce conflict is: ((x), y) which translates to the sequence: LPAREN LPAREN IDENTIFIER RPAREN COMMA IDENTIFIER RPAREN.
The shift/reduce parser will utilize the two actions shift and reduce to try parse this input sequence:

Shift: LPAREN
Shift: LPAREN
Shift: IDENTIFIER
Shift: RPAREN
Reduce: 3

Stack: LPAREN identifierlist
However, note that this sequence is also possible:

Shift: LPAREN
Shift: LPAREN
Shift: IDENTIFIER
Reduce: 2

Stack: LPAREN LPAREN identifierlist
Note that the first version tried an extra shift action, while the other version tried immediately the reduce action once applicable. This illustrates the shift/reduce conflict the parser sees that it can do either of the two actions and must choose one of the two.
As explained earlier Bison will default to choosing the shift action leaving you to the first version. Now the parser tries to continue from this stack: LPAREN LPAREN identifierlist, however, there is no production rule that starts with identifierlist thus it stops parsing and ends up in a syntax error.
Grammar ambiguity
identifierlist: identifier COMMA identifierlist
              | identifier
              | LPAREN identifier RPAREN
              | LPAREN identifierlist RPAREN
;

In this piece of grammar there are 2 ways to parse the terminal sequence: LPAREN IDENTIFIER RPAREN
Namely we can utilize either the third rule, or the fourth rule on which we apply the second rule to consume the IDENTIFIER terminal.
As a terminal sequence can be parsed in more than one way, one can expect that there will be issues. It is best to avoid these scenarios at all cost.
In this case removing the third production rules results in an equivalent grammar with less ambiguity issues.
How to solve shift/reduce issues?
There is not a single method to solve shift/reduce or reduce/reduce conflicts. This is the hard part of making grammars that requires some practice to do perfect.
There are various strategies that can help:

Utilize the GLR version of bison. This explores both action branches. It only works if this grammar is unambiguous which it is not.
Modularize the grammar, in this case the identifierlist tries to provide a solution for multiple distinct syntactic structures. By splitting these responsibilities over multiple nonterminals it can help you better reason about issues.
Removing 'obvious' ambiguities as these guarantee that the grammar is incorrect and will add conflicts.
Try and error

A possible solution
Applying the aforementioned techniques leads me to the following equivalent grammar:
identifierlist: LPAREN element_list RPAREN
              | identifier
    
element_list: identifierlist COMMA element_list
            | identifierlist

This grammar has no shift/reduce or reduce/reduce conflicts. Furthermore, I have tested this grammar on both issue sets and multiple others and it fixed the parse issue.
When you encounter future issues in the rest of your grammar try the techniques I mentioned before. I hope this helps you understand the issue more deeply and how to solve it.
